# Search by multiple tags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, search

I'd like to be able to search for questions by multiple tags; for example "questions tagged 'nhibernate' and 'web-services'".

I can get close by searching for "nhibernate web-services" but the results tend to be a few questions that relate to both terms--but much more largely just questions that relate to one or the other.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want a search for "nhibernate OR web-services", right? Any one tag is sufficient for the question to be present in the result.

Comment: @nik no, you're going to need to give raven his point back--I'm looking for an AND search

Comment: Tag search FAQ page can be found here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-you-search-for-specific-tags-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can. Search for `[tag1] [tag2]` to search for questions with both tags.

Comment: +1, This is better than typing in the URL :)

Comment: @nik: agreed, I did not know you could do this.  Pretty cool.

Comment: @DanDascalescu - as you found out in your Q&A, it is not broken. Maybe you could remove your comment, it misled me :)

Comment: sorry but this does not work. codegolf.stackexchange.com and `[code-golf] [java]` in search box will ignore my Java tag.

Comment: @Blauhirn Use quotes: `"[code-golf] [java]"`

Comment: @Navin sorry but no, this totally does not do it, try it out yourself: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22[code-golf]+[java]%22 . there are plenty questions tagged witih code-golf AND java.

Comment: @Blauhirn It appears to work on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%5Bopenssl%5D+%5Bc%5D%22 (If it doesn't work, ask a new question here and report the bug)

Comment: It does not work for anonymous users: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243960/multiple-tags-search-broken-when-searching-as-anonymous-user

Comment: can we search with `OR` like [tag1] or [tag2] ?

Answer (score 6):

**Updated**:
AhA! Mea Culpa! I did not appreciate the difference between these two ways.

- Search: [nhibernate][web-services]
- Search: nhibernate web-services

Something to do with the way I am used to get the effect of "[nhibernate][web-services]"
directly by typing that in the URL as **"questions/tagged/web-services+nhibernate"**.

Taking away all my comments and leaving this answer around as something I learned here.

---

Old:
[The OR method] Exists as described [here](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/).

Try [**tags** or **search**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags%20or%20search)
Or, [**nhibernate** or **web-services**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate%20or%20web-services)

Comment: It was doing OR, he wanted AND.

Comment: +1 for (undocumented?) `OR` search

Comment: This updated approach is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you 

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do a simple ANDed search, there is another way to accomplish this, without actually using the search interface.

By going to one of the tag pages, using `[nhibernate]` as an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate), if the additional tags you want to search for are popular enough within that tag to show up on the right side of the screen, clicking on one of those tags automatically adds an AND to the filter.

So if you're browsing questions in `[nhibernate]`, clicking on the `[mapping]` tag on the right side takes you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate+mapping).

This is a really easy way to browse through questions, and without doing a lot of typing. As I mentioned, the tags you're looking for do have to be popular within the subset of questions shown in the list, but once you've narrowed things down by 2 tags, the list is generally short enough to just browse through all the questions to find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can.  Type this in your browser's address bar:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nhibernate web-services

Comment: That is an AND operation

Comment: That's what he asked for, "questions tagged 'nhibernate' and 'web-services'"

Comment: The part where he says "but the results tend to be a few questions that relate to both terms" seems to suggest he wants the search to be more generic (OR rather than AND). I re-read the question later and asked a clarification...

Comment: @nik sorry for the ambiguity--I was trying to say my search for nhibernate+web-services got a *few* good hits but most were just one or the other