# search within a tag

Tags: feature-request

Hi,

I think it would be pretty cool, if I can select a tag and search for questions within that tag only. To be more awesome, the ability to select multiple tags and search within it

Comment: Awesome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+sql - Searching dupe...

Comment: Found: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10754/search-by-multiple-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature already exists. To narrow down your search to a tag just add `[tagName1] [tagName2]` in your query.

[See here for all search options you can use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=)

Comment: sweet, I did not know and now I know.

Thanks :-)

Comment: You are pretty slow.

Comment: @John Smithers I guess I am one of the kid left behind... way behind lol

Comment: I meant Brandon.

Comment: Indeed I am. I actually was looking for a link to the search help page, but couldn't remember how I had gotten there before. Took me a minute to remember to just perform a blank search.