# How can I search by more than one tag?

Tags: support, tags, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search by multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10754/search-by-multiple-tags)

How can I search by more than one tag?

If I knew how to do this maybe I would have found my own answer by now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the search box and search and use `[...]` to denote tags:

```
[tag1] [tag2] something interesting
```

Comment: thanks. and with that I found the question has already been asked. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10754/search-by-multiple-tags