# Is there any way to filter question on SO?

Tags: support, tags, search, tag-filters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Search by multiple tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10754/search-by-multiple-tags)

Is there any way to see the all question which are tagged as `android` + `c` ?

Comment: You did try to enter that into search, did you?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope you typed `android` + `c` in to that search box.

[image]

This is what you'll get if you didn't.

[image]

Put the terms in square brackets if you want to force tag search.

Searching for [android](/questions/tagged/android) OR [c](/questions/tagged/c) isn't possible, you'll have to do things like force one term to be a text keyword & the other to be a tag keyword.

Like so https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%2Bandroid+c