# What is the best way to find questions to old answers?

Tags: support, search

I just want to know what the best way is to find previous questions that may answer mine (on Stack Overflow).

I try to search, but I tend to get too many irrelevant results. What's your best method for researching a Stack Overflow topic, before posting a question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Searching by value: A bit more documentation needed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305281/282094) (on MSE that's a valid duplicate, even if unanswered), and  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5229/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching

Answer (score 7):

You can use Google with the site limited to Stack Overflow.

For example: [`site:http://stackoverflow.com "Python IDE"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%20%22Python%20IDE%22).

Answer (score 6):

When you type in your new question, watch the suggested topics that come up.  Phrase it a few different ways before you're sure that nothing already has you covered.

But, redundancy is OK.  Think of it like Google -- if you try a few different sets of search terms and nothing comes up, then there needs to be an entry with those terms.  So go ahead and ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

Now that we're public, you could try googling for your search terms with `site:stackoverflow.com` on the end.

Google often does a better job than the built-in search - it's their core business after all.

Answer (score 1):

1. Search Google
2. Switch to searching [Google Groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Groups) if you don't find anything on the web

- Search Google with:

> site:stackoverflow.com *searchterm(s)*

- Use Stack Overflow's search and restrict your search to specific tags by enclosing them in square brackets:

> *searchterm(s)* [tag1] [tag2]

- type **just** keywords into the *Ask Question Title* input and press tab to see suggestions 
  (currently this will search *just* the topic titles for those keywords)

Answer (score 0):

When I have a problem (almost always [C#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) [.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) related due to my line of work), I usually google search first. Blogs are good, and [MSDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network) can be quite good. Those question/answer sites that make you pay are horrible, newsgroups are pretty bad too.

If that fails, this site can be pretty awesome. If the search and tags fail you, just post, I suppose. Not many other options.

Answer (score 0):

Currently search and browsing by tags are your only option. (How else do you "find" something besides searching?)

If you clarify your question with an example, we might be able to help you use the search better.

If you're looking for more sophisticated filtering, for example a search like

answered:today votes:10+ (asp OR vbscript)

Then you will want to post that feature on [stackoverflow.uservoice.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20090219112537/http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com:80/)

Comment: This answer is completely obsolete. All of it.

Answer (score 0):

When I can't find something on Google because I either don't know the correct terms to use or the terms are way too broad for an effective search, I jump on irc.freenode.net and join the official chatroom for what ever language/framework I'm having issues with.

The problem with freenode is you are talking to people so you have to be slightly more communicative than when you're talking to a search engine. The great thing about freenode is you are talking to a person that can probably grasp your problem better than a computer could. It's hit or miss on whether you get someone helpful but I've had good results on some of my more bizarre questions.