# Allow "or" in searches using tags for Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

It would be awesome if I could pass a list of tags to search for out of which I am given questions which are in either of the categories.

Comment: Hmm, you can do it in tag searches (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request+or+search) but apparently not when you're searching for text within those tags.

Comment: You also can't do it if you add qualifiers like answers:1, there's another request out there on that one.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176155/searching-using-both-and-and-or-sum-of-products-or-product-of-sums/176159#176159   (some use case examples)

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is a way. See [this for a detailed answer.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5230/161537)

If you want to try either C# or Scala, just

```
[c#] or [scala]
```

---

For both C# and Scala

```
[c#] [scala]
```

To have only C# and ignore overlapping Scala

```
[c#] -[scala]
```

Note: No space between `-` and `[`