# How do I do an "or" search?

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow “or” in searches using tags for Stack Overflow and similar sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42338/allow-or-in-searches-using-tags-for-stack-overflow-and-similar-sites)

I'm sure this is a very newbie question but how do I do an "or" search?  I tried searching for "[windows-phone-7] [wp7] [wp7-dev]" but it only gives me one result with all those tags rather than all results with any of those tags.  I searched meta for how to do "or" searches but didn't find an answer.  Found one question saying you could do "or" searches with tags but not combining it with search terms.  At any rate I can't seem to get any "or" search to work.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42338/allow-or-in-searches-using-tags-for-stack-overflow-and-similar-sites