# searching using both "and" and "or" (sum-of-products or product-of-sums)

Tags: support, search, tag-search

I would like to do a search on stackoverflow for all questions tagged:

`([concurrent] or [multithreading]) and ([c] or [c++])`

I'd even be happy if I could do a search for
`([c] or [c++]) and [multithreading]`.

But I can't figure out the syntax.

**Edit**: part of the problem (as pointed out be @Hugo) is that the box in the upper right corner that tells you what you queried doesn't parenthesize correctly.  Querying `([c] or [c++])[multithreading] is:question` (which really returns the right thing) says it returns:

[image]

(which is the same picture you'll get if you query `[c] or ([c++][multithreading])`!

**Edit 2**: A second part of the problem is that the `or` operator seems to behave differently than the `[or]` operator.  Sometimes one works, sometimes not, sometimes the other.  A third part of the problem is that adding the `is:question` qualifier seems to dramatically change the results.  (See the comments below @Hugo's answer.)

I've tried
`[multithreading]([c] or [c++])` (and `([c] or [c++]) [multithreading]`) but get questions tagged `[c] or ([c++] and [multithreading])`.

I've tried
`[multithreading]([c] [or] [c++])` bug got questions tagged `([multithreading] and [c]) or [c++]`.

I've tried
`[c][multithreading] or [c++][multithreading]` but get questions tagged
`[multithreading] or ([c++] and [c] and [multithreading])`???

On the other hand
`[c][multithreading] [or] [c++][multithreading]` seems to *work* but `[c][multithreading] [or] [c++][multithreading] is:question` returns *nothing*.

Even stranger querying `[multithreading][c] or [multithreading][c++]` gives questions tagged `[c] or ([multithreading] and [multithreading] and [c++])` (yes, `[multithreading]` twice!)

How do I do a search that involves both "and" and "or" operators?  Is there a predictable syntax I should be using?

Comment: @Telthien: I orginally had this as [support] but changed it to [bug] when it became clear (as I discussed it with the answerer, and did my edits) that there are a lot of serious problems with the search feature.  You changed it back to [support], so you must disagree.  What should I do to report the bugs?

Comment: My reasoning for changing it to support was, even though this reveals bugs in the system, it's technically a support question ("How d o I do a..."). If you have found bugs, you can start a new question to report them, though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Searching [`[multithreading]([c] or [c++]) is:question`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmultithreading%5D%28%5Bc%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%29+is%3Aquestion) does work. But it does need the `is:question` else the search results are completely non-relevant.

Here are some results (in the search) that I found that corresponds to borderline cases :

- [c++ and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188/are-c-reads-and-writes-of-an-int-atomic)
- [c and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665419/do-threads-have-a-distinct-heap)
- [c and c++ and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875989/does-multithreading-emphasize-memory-fragmentation)

I think these covers all the possible case of what you wanted.

---

[`([concurrent] or [multithreading])([c] or [c++]) is:question`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%28%5Bconcurrent%5D+or+%5Bmultithreading%5D%29%28%5Bc%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%29+is%3Aquestion) seems to work as expected also. (With the `is:question` only, else it does not work.)

---

Your parenthesis are wrong I think. It's written `[c] or [c++][multithreading]` which seems to mean `([c] or [c++])[multithreading]`. The ORs seem to have precedence over the ANDs *(in the UI)*

When you put this `([concurrent] or [multithreading])([c] or [c++])` it outputs `[concurrent] or [multithreading][c] or [c++]`. And the precedence goes to ORs, as you can see because of the search results covering all possible cases.

Comment: Interesting that adding `is:question` gets the right result (even though the box on the right still says you are getting [c] or ([c++] and [multithreading]).  Why?

Comment: @WanderingLogic I've edited! I do think it's just because they don't output parenthesis.

Comment: Okay, even more bizarre.  `[c][multithreading] [or] [c++][multithreading]` (note the brackets around `or`) works (the box on the right actually is correct in this case too.) But: `[c][multithreading] [or] [c++][multithreading] is:question` returns _nothing_!

Comment: @WanderingLogic this one is weird ! Really don't know why!

Comment: I see what you mean about them not outputting the parens, but there is still something very broken here.  `[multithreading]([c] or [c++])` (no `is:question`) really is outputting `[c] or ([c++] and [multithreading])`.  The first 6 results have nothing to do with either multithreading or c++ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20or%20c%2b%2b%20multithreading.

Comment: @WanderingLogic that's effectively weird u_U!