# tag search summary with "or" operators are not parenthesized correctly

Tags: bug, search, tag-search

The box in the upper right hand corner that summarizes your current search does not parenthesize correctly.

Consider typing the following query in the search box:
[`([c] or [c++]) [multithreading] is:question`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%28%5Bc%5D+or+%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%29+%5Bmultithreading%5D+is%3Aquestion).  This really does return all 5052 [multithreading] questions that are also tagged either ([c] or [c++]) but the box shows:

[image: picture of search result]

Most people would consider this incorrect.  The "and" operator takes precedence over the "or" operator.

Now consider the query [`[c] [or] ([c++] [multithreading])`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%20or%20c%2b%2b%20multithreading)

This query returns all 95134 questions about either c or (c++ and multithreading), but the box in  the upper right hand corner seems to indicate that you asked for the same thing as the previous query.

I can suggest two options: either actually include parenthesis when necessary (the first query above) or flatten into sum-of-products form before displaying.

Note: This bug report grew out of the discussion with respect to the support question I asked here: [searching using both "and" and "or" (sum-of-products or product-of-sums)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176155/searching-using-both-and-and-or-sum-of-products-or-product-of-sums).