# Related tags list does not show when tag search uses "or" and "is:q" is added with additional tags

Tags: bug, tags, tag-search, related-tags

When selecting multiple tags, separated by "or", the related tags list shows additional tags with their count. Selecting any of those tags does not limit the search, unless one adds "is:q" to the search box. However, adding "is:q" to the search box eliminates the related tags list; thus preventing further refinement.

For example a search for [legislation](/questions/tagged/legislation) or [regulation](/questions/tagged/regulation),

https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legislation+or+regulation

shows 141 questions, with related questions showing [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states) with 72.

Selecting [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states) shows 112.

Placing "is:q" in the search box shows 72, but the related tags list no longer shows. This prevents the showing of counts or refinement by selecting additional tags. In effect, those tags must be added manually without necessarily knowing what tags are related.

---

This extends the previous bug report: [tag search summary with “or” operators are not parenthesized correctly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176177/824951), to include the loss of the related tags list.

Comment: There's a discrepancy in the related-tag counter and the way the related tag is added. If searching for tag (A or B), the related-tag counter for C shows the count of questions with ((A or B) and C), but clicking on C searches for questions with (A or (B and C)).

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. Adding `is:q` (or any other operator/keyword) causes related tags to disappear even when searching for one tag. It looks like the "Related tags" feature is only supported on `/questions/tagged` and not `/search`, which kind of makes sense.

Comment: @41686d6564 - As I understand it, "is:q" selects only questions, rather than questions and answers, during text search. As long as the search box contains only tags, no answers are shown. Thus, it seems like a bug to have to add "is:q" to get the proper question list when there is no search for text.

Comment: Yes, the bug is most likely in the discrepancy that @bobble explained. I'm just saying that focusing on the fact that the related tags don't show in text search is likely to get you a [status-bydesign]. So, you might want to edit the question to clarify that the bug report has to do with the results list and not with whether or not the related tags are displayed.

Comment: @41686d6564 - Updated to refer to a previous bug report.