# How can I filter questions by given tags?

Tags: support, tags, search

I would like to filter the questions in SO by different tags.

For example, if I have tags `java` and `jsf` I would like to list all the questions, which are tagged with  `java` **or** `jsf` (or both).

If I open, for instance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf+java, the resulting page contains only the questions which are tagged with both of the tags.

Is this possible ?

Comment: writing "or" between them seems to work

Comment: Great! Thank you! :)

Comment: related : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176155/searching-using-both-and-and-or-sum-of-products-or-product-of-sums/176159#176159

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Richart Tingle said, writing "or" between tags (adding `+or+`) works just fine. Using your URL as an example:

Questions containing both:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf+java

Questions containing one or both:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf+or+java

Comment: Slightly suprised this isn't in the [help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), yours Richart

Comment: I have been using SO for sometime and didn't know about it