# Tag searching/rss with boolean logic?

Tags: support, tags, feed

In addition to answering recently posted questions, I also like to catch up once a day on specific topics.  Is it possible to subscribe to an RSS feed which allows something along the lines of:

```
 Java AND (best-practices OR unit-testing OR security)
```

which would show any post tagged Java and one or more of the other 3?

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-specific-tags/5230#5230 . I haven't tried any of that stuff on RSS feeds personally, and I don't think the bracketed nesting logic is implemented. Let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to perform that search if you distribute the java tag:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+best-practices+OR+java+unit-testing+OR+java+security
```

And here is the RSS feed:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java%2bbest-practices%2bor%2bjava%2bunit-testing%2bor%2bjava%2bsecurity&sort=newest
```

Comment: Haha, nice one! (and thanks for the feed too)

Answer (score 0):

This RSS feed URI syntax worked for me (using Google Reader):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=gwt+-gxt+-smartgwt&sort=newest
```

Items containing either `gxt` or `smartgwt` tags have been successfully excluded from the list of questions about GWT.