# Email subscription to a combination of tags (using AND operator)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, email, tag-filters, subscription

Lately I've noticed that hovering over tags opens a mini info-window with tag related data and activities including email subscription option. Great!

But instead of subscribing to just a single tag I'd rather subscribe to a combination:

> tagX **and** tagY **and** tagZ ...

giving me a much better selection of questions delivered to my email inbox.

Similar to viewing questions with a particular tag. You can always click on any of the related tags and you get a subset of questions that have both tags (the first one **and** the second one as well) and not either.

Is this kind of email subscription possible or are there any plans on developing it?

### Edit

Tag sets on StackExchange (as suggested by @Barry) don't work, because they are combined by an **OR** operator instead of an **AND**. A tag set therefore widens the filter instead of narrowing it. Just so you know this question hasn't been sufficiently answered yet.

Comment: and possibly the AND (NOT tag2) option?

Comment: @RD01: That would make it more complicated. but if someone would develop such a tag set combination interface it could support all three boolean operators yes. **AND**, **OR** and **NOT**. This would cover every possible tag combination. But I would be satisfied with a tag set that I could select whether I want them or-ed or and-ed...

Comment: I would really like this as well. It would be really useful for me since I want to filter out a quite specific set of questions. The filters on StackExchange are nice, but not being able to set multiple tags that must all be set makes it a very limited filter.

Comment: But how far do you go? Maybe some people will start wanting **AND**, **OR**, **NOT**, **XOR**, **XNOR**, **NOR**, and **NAND**! (not really, just joking :P)

Comment: any possibility of this being reviewed? I could actually live with a simple solution where you run a search (eg "[html5] [video]") and have the ability to save it as a named favorite - doesn't need a big complex UI...

Answer (score 6):

Firstly, I emphatically support the request to allow using "and" with tags in the Stack Exchange filters. However, since that is now officially "status-declined" the next best things I've found are some Google Chrome extensions:

- [Question Monitor for Stack Exchange](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/question-monitor-for-stac/bnnkhapbhkejookmhgpgaikfdoegkmdp)
- [New Q!](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-q/bffhpbgmmflmoacglmdnilfjkeeokkfn)

Comment: @Emmett: The reviews, downloads, and general interest in these types of extensions might give some insight into the interest in the use cases that are not satisfied by stack exchange. Additionally, as both extensions provide support for an "and" operator with a pretty simple UI, it might help imagine a non-convoluted UI for the feature.

Comment: The link to New Q! is broken.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't supported right now. The primary reason isn't technical, but because the filter creation UI is already somewhat complicated, and it's hard to imagine adding support for other operators (e.g. AND, NOT) without making it convoluted. Additionally, we think that OR satisfies the vast majority of use cases.

Comment: I assume when you say `it isn't supported right now.` there is a chance that this will be supported in the near future?

Comment: Yea, there's a chance the entire filter UI will be revamped in the future.

Comment: Would really like this.... As I said in my post, I'd really like to see people taggin questions with C# *AND* MongoDB for example...

Comment: *we think that OR satisfies the vast majority of use cases*: based on what? On existing subscriptions? No wonder because there's no **and** support. I expect this to be a broadly subjective statement based on no real user testing.

Comment: As a work-around, you could use Google Alerts to get updates about questions that are relevant to a search query (such as `site:stackoverflow.com java javascript` for questions that are relevant to Java and Javascript.)

Comment: OR most certainly does NOT satisfy the majority of use cases - far from it.  Im really interested in following C# async but when I subscribe to Asynchronous tag the majority of results are java and python - which don't interest me at all...  This is REALLY short sighted of SE.

Comment: @Emmett why not just piggyback off [search](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-specific-tags)? Filters would be infinitely more flexible and the UI would be reduced to one box.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be possible to get an RSS feed of questions that match all the given tags, e.g. `http://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag/timezone%20c%2b%2b`, which only shows questions that have both the `[c++]` tag and the `[timezone]` tag.

From there, you can use your RSS reader of choice to receive updates when new questions are posted.  There also seem to be services that will email you when an RSS feed is updated (e.g. https://blogtrottr.com/, although I have no experience with them).

Answer (score -3):

Create your own or use existing tag sets on https://stackexchange.com/  You can specify one or more tags for one or more sites across the stack exchange network.

You can also receive email notifications for tag sets.

[See this blog post for further details](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/tag-sets-on-stack-exchange/)

Comment: **Doesn't work as expected**. Instead of combining tags with **AND** operator they are combined with **OR** which means **not narrowing** but **widening my selection** of questions. As stated in the question **I want AND operator** between all tags in the set.