# Web searchable question tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, tag-search

I was wondering whether Stackoverflow could list all question tags in a certain way so we could actually search questions using Google? SEO experts could provide some valuable insight into this.

`"asp.net-mvc" site:stackoverflow.com` for instance is a good Google query that would list questions with *asp.net-mvc* tags, but adding `"routing"` is not necessarily related to question tags rather than free text.

There's this great Google service called [Google Alerts](http://www.google.com/alerts) where one can subscribe to certain Google search results. I can see this as a better version of the Stackexchange tag subscription which is only able to subscribe to multiple tags using **OR** operator instead of AND.

See my [feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78107/137977) about it.

### A suggestion

From the lack of my SEO knowledge I may be totally wrong but I can still make a suggestion.

Question tags could be pre/appended with certain characters that can be specified in a Google query. These tag *markers* would be part of question content in a hidden `div` os they wouldn't be visible (or set with `text-indent: -1000em` or something similar to make them invisible to humans but visible to search crawlers).

They could be written as

```
TAGasp.net-mvcTAG
```

So you could write a search query as

```
"TAGasp.net-mvcTAG" "TAGroutingTAG" site:stackoverflow.com
```

The best suggestion would of course be, to implement **AND** operator on StackExchange email tag subscription. That would of course be best. That's also suggested [by the other linked question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78107/137977).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no known way to do this.

Google does not support any reliable (read: searchable) form of metadata about webpages in the way you are describing.

I'd love to be proven wrong, but there's nothing I've found in the last few years of looking.

Comment: See my added suggestion in the question.