# Allow users to save combinations of tags as favorites

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

I have saved some favorite tags for easy access. I'd like to save favorite combinations of tags as well. Suppose I generally want to see posts tagged with [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [winforms](/questions/tagged/winforms) **and** (not "or"!) [controls](/questions/tagged/controls). To do this now, I need to click on all those tags one by one. Please allow us to save combinations so we can easily access the questions we want; if you do so, the favorite tags function will really serve its purpose.

Comment: @KevinVermeer: Sorry but I cant see why my question is same as them. I am talking about a basket of tags, so if click the basket all posts of those tags will appear. And now, we click the tags one by one to add a tag to an existing one. I am not sure if its same as the link you provided.Thanks

Comment: A basket?  Do you mean a [tag filter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-filters), like those on [http://stackexchange.com/filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters)?  What's the URL of the page where you 'click the tags one by one to add a tag to an existing one'?

Comment: There's an [existing request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78107/email-subscription-to-a-combination-of-tags-using-and-operator) for an e-mail version of this.

Comment: @KevinVermeer: exactly, i am talking about the tag filter. seeing posts associated with tags. eg. C#, Winforms. Those light blue buttons on right side. I want to save combination of tags as my favorite

Comment: @PopularDemand: You edited the heading perfectly

Answer (score 2):

You can do a search like:

> user:me [c#] [winforms]

and see them all, but right now there is no way to search in your favorites.