# Subscribe to filter with multiple tags ANDed together

Tags: support, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Email subscription to a combination of tags (using AND operator)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78107/email-subscription-to-a-combination-of-tags-using-and-operator)

I've figured out how to subscribe to a filter and get a daily email. I've figured out how to search for 2 tags ANDed together, but I can't figure out how to subscribe to a filter with multiple tags.  When I put "[r] [bootstrap]" in the subscription filter it seems to only filter on one of the tags. Am I missing something?

Comment: By 'filter', do you mean http://stackexchange.com/filters or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r+bootstrap? The former should be really easy, if it's the former, can you link to that filter?  (ex. I have a filter at http://stackexchange.com/filters/12100/electronics-questions-not-on-ee)

Comment: Keven,  Thanks for taking the time to respond.  I created a filter at http://stackexchange.com/filters/25767/r-bootstrap however this shows posts that match either [r] or [bootstrap].  I want to match both [r] and [bootstrap].  I'm sure I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Ah, now I understand the problem.  This is probably a duplicate of [this old question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78107/146495).  No decent answers there, either.