# Is it possible to subscribe to a filter where tag1 AND tag1 are present on the question?

Tags: support, tags

I realize this is possible for searching, i.e. by tag as [tag1] [and] [tag2] and I quite possibly may be overlooking something obvious. But I am not able to figure out to describe an email filter that has the condition tag1 AND tag2 are present on the question.

It seems my only options are to select one tag at a time or no tags at all and that a filter with multiple tags will match any questions with one or more of the selected tags. I would like to be able to set a filter which requires two or more tags are on a given question.

Is this possible, am I just going about this in completely the wrong way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it's not possible. (As far as I know!)

The feature request about [that has been refused in the past](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78107/email-subscription-to-a-combination-of-tags-using-and-operator).

This was not planned as of right now because, it would need too much changes to the "question filter" and as of right now, making theses changes was impossible. It might be reconsidered if they change the filter engine, but that is not planned.

> This isn't supported right now. The primary reason isn't technical, but because the filter creation UI is already somewhat complicated, and it's hard to imagine adding support for other operators (e.g. AND, NOT) without making it convoluted. Additionally, we think that OR satisfies the vast majority of use cases. -- Emmett

Comment: Giving a banana to the first finding the link, I really can't find it right now!

Comment: Thank you. I couldn't seem to find the duplicate, so apologies for posting this. (I'm not surprised it's been requested before, but was surprised it didn't seem to turn up searching.)

Comment: @maxcountryman well that's alright I've been looking at it for the last 15mins and can't find it haha!

Comment: @maxcountryman I've found the topic if you ever want to learn more about it!

Comment: Sure, I'd like to read it if you have it handy. Thanks! Edit: Ah see you added in your answer.

Comment: @maxcountryman (oops forgot to specify I've edited it in the post !) See the comment feed on emmett answer for info and scott answer for provide alternatives!

Comment: Thanks again! I think a Google Alert should suffice. Not quite as good but better than nothing. Really appreciate your time digging that up.