# Create filter and subscription on combined tags

Tags: support, tags, tag-filters

How can I create a filter with AND, OR and NOT?

Let's say I want to create a filter with: `async-await` AND (`C#` OR `Visual-Basic`)

Can I do it?

Comment: Nope, no such thing exists and [feature request asking to add support in this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78107/email-subscription-to-a-combination-of-tags-using-and-operator) was declined.