# Quickselect of operator between tags, for quicksearch by tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

By trying to search this: `hasaccepted:0 excel vba excel-vba`

I started to read more about the search options inside SO, and found

[how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-specific-tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-specific-tags)

Now the answer by Jeff M from community wiki was quite nice, but I wondered why there can't be an additional section between *related tags* and *questions tagged* to specify the operator.

It should be easy to build in and would provide a great improvement to fast tag-search, having only to click on a tag-like OR, AND or XOR button. There is even enough space to extend this with tag-like buttons for `hasaccepted` or `is:question`.

So please be so nice and tell me, if this feature will/is/was considered and what the result is/was, if there is one.

Comment: seriously, is there a way to search [excel] [or] [vba] [or] [excel-vba] hasaccepted:0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new search engine this should work for you:

```
[excel] or [vba] hasaccepted:0
```

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexcel%5D+or+%5Bvba%5D+hasaccepted%3A0

Comment: nice, already tested and found something to answer ;)