# More efficient search/monitoring with grouped favorite tags

Tags: feature-request, search, tag-watching, tag-search

As I am currently monitoring different tags (like excel and vba and excel-vba), I already asked for a [quicker option to search for them with or-connect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146147/quickselect-of-operator-between-tags-for-quicksearch-by-tag).

But laziness provides efficiency, so I asked my self - why can't I have favorite groups in my favorite tags section. Then I could put my default vba/excel-related tags in ONE group and by clicking on it, I would get all new question to those tags.

Maybe such a feature exists in another way, please point me to it. However, I think such self-defined groups in the favorite-tags section could really speedup a search for questions, one is possibly able to answer.