# Setting a tag subscription with more than one tag

Tags: support, tags, search

I'm trying to set up filtering on TWO tags for on stackoverflow.com

I am aware of this post:
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/10/tags-and-tags-or-tags/

However, I don't think this answers my question. I am on the page:
https://stackexchange.com/filters/12345/my-filter

I want to specify a new rule with 2 tags, say "foo" and "bar". I want to filter only questions on stackoverflow.com that have both the "foo" tag AND the "bar" tag. However, it doesn't appear as though I can set this, when reading at the top of the page:
"Any question that matches one of these tags will be displayed in the filter."

Am I missing something? It seems to me to be a common request i.e. I want to only read questions about the "lisp" and "RDF".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a tag to your "Favorite" tags list, it doesn't 100% guarentee you would ever only see questions of those tags.

The SO engine will give those a huge bonus in visiblity on your "Interesting" page, plus color them in a yellowish orange to indicate that they are in your favorites.

If you want strictly questions matching list or RDF, you can use the search function to achieve that. i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rdf+or+lisp

For more information, see the **[FAQ entry on tag searching](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-specific-tags)**.

Comment: Thanks. It would be really useful if a filter to this effect could be set up, to get email notifications when people are asking a question containing both tags (like the filtering rules using only one filter). This is more convenient than having to log in and search each time - email notification are more convenient.

Comment: @RobStewart: As for email notifications, you can subscribe to the RSS feed. Also, I'm always logged in, so searching isn't a problem.