# Does Stack Overflow has search according to tags?

Tags: support, tags, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I search for questions with specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-specific-tags)

Stack Overflow has a global search which searches all tags, but is it possible to search results according to tags?

As at times user needs to search a question limited to tags say [php](/questions/tagged/php) or [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) etc.

If not, can this be implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type the tag(s) between square brackets in the search box.

> [tag-name] other-kewyords

Answer (score 3):

You can search within any tags by using `[tagname]` in the search box.

For e.g. if you want to search for questions tagged `JavaScript`, you can do this by adding [javascript] in search box

[Questions tagged `JavaScript`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

You can also add multiple tags like this: [`[javascript] [html]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+html)

You can add other keywords behind tags like this: [`[javascript] dynamic`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D%20dynamic)
This will show questions tagged JavaScript and contains `dynamic` word

For more see this [search tips](https://stackoverflow.com/search)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. To search for all questions tagged with [support](/questions/tagged/support), enter

```
[support]
```

into the search.