# Blacklist for tags filter on Stack Exchange

Tags: feature-request

I have a lot of unneeded data in the "Filtered questions" list of Stack Exchange. For example, I choose tag [linux], but I don't want to see something about [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) or [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29). Or I choose tag [C], but I don't want to see something about [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV).

It would be very pretty if filters in "Filtered questions" included not only a whitelist for tags, but also a blacklist with priority to the blacklist.

Comment: You can [include and exclude tags while searching](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5229/167443)

Comment: @Jim, but I want such functionality in my "Filtered" list.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do that (which is why I posted my comment as a comment and not an answer - thought you might be able to make use of it until you get a solid answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by URL formatting mentioned in the FAQ [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5230/212576). Another way is to prefix a hyphen (`-`) for the tags you don't want in your results when using the search bar.

So, for questions with [c](/questions/tagged/c) but not [opencv](/questions/tagged/opencv), use the following:

```
[c] -[opencv] is:q
```

or

```
[c] -[opencv] question:yes
```

Comment: You don't understand my question: I don't want this in search form, but in "filters" list! BTW, I've tried both your variants of searching requests: both don't work!

Comment: Add them to ignored tags, @Eddy_Em

Comment: I can't find field "ignored tags" in settings of my filter.