# Markdown URL formatting error when preceded by tag

Tags: bug, tags, markdown, hyperlinks, editor

I faced this bug when I was answering [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188895/212576). For reproducing the bug:

```
[tag:sth] [link][2]
```

and it'll be parsed as: [sth](/questions/tagged/sth) [link][2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

As one can notice, the word `link` is not actually converted to link, but the numbered reference is hyper-linked.

I'll leave a screenshot in case the bug gets fixed ;-).

> [image: Picture with freehand]

Answer (score 3):

I agree it's a bug in markddown, but easy to overcome. One way around this is to use direct link:

```
[tag:sth] [link](http://www.google.com)
```

Which results in:

[sth](/questions/tagged/sth) [link](http://www.google.com)

This can also be fixed by inserting a non-breaking space, like this:

```
[tag:sth]&nbsp;[link][1]
```

Which renders like this:

[sth](/questions/tagged/sth) [link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @Richard nice one, +1! :)

Comment: Yeah, I was going to suggest adding an HTML comment, but a space works even better. Interestingly, I find myself *always* using direct/inline links. The footnote-style syntax is just far too cumbersome.