# Why is this Stack Overflow URL returning unexpected results?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, search

I have been reading through some threads on here to try to refine my list of questions on Stack Overflow. The most useful one I found is here: [How do I search for questions with (or without) specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-specific-tags).

However, after experimenting with this for a while I am still having difficulty getting the results I would expect. Here is a URL I have tried:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/python%20or%20sql%20or%20sqlite%20or%20plsql%20or%20oracle%20or%20windows-7%20or%20cmd%20or%20excel~%20or%20access~%20or%20vba~%20-django%20-.net?tab=newest
```

What I am trying to get here is something along the lines of questions with any of the following tags (Python, sql, sqlite, plsql, oracle, windows-7, cmd, excel, access or vba) with wild cards around the last few to include extensions, but excluding questions with tags for dango or .net.

The list of tags shown on the right appears to be in line with what I expected:

[image]

However, the list of questions shown do not appear to be relevant to the tags listed at all e.g. :

[image]

Am I doing something specific wrong here or is the criteria just too long / complex and I therefore get everything?

I was previously using a simpler version which was working okay, but I was hoping to be able to build a few exclusions in:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/python+sql+oracle+windows-7+excel+excel-vba+access+access-vba?tab=newest
```

**EDIT (POST ANSWER)**

In case anyone viewing this is interested the url I am now using is:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+sql+or+sqlite+or+plsql+or+oracle+or+windows-7+or+cmd+or+excel+or+access+or+vba+excel-vba+access-vba+-django+-.net+-google-api+-flask+-pyramid+-c#?sort=newest&pageSize=50
```

I have dropped the unanswered tag and replaced the spaces with +, seems to work perfectly now.

Comment: Ick, this is the *unanswered* tab, not certain this works at all there..

Comment: Dango? Or Django?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if the unanswered tab does *not* support `NOT` queries in combination with `OR`; remove the negated tags and your list works, up to a point:

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/python+or+sql+or+sqlite+or+plsql+or+oracle+or+windows-7+or+cmd+or+excel+or+access~+or+vba~

The wildcards are also ignored (stripped from the tag).

This at least gives:

[image: unanswered limited tags]

You can use a `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged` URL to expand those wildcards first, then switching it back to `unanswered`:

https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/python+or+sql+or+sqlite+or+plsql+or+oracle+or+windows-7+or+cmd+or+excel+or+access-vba+or+accessibility+or+access-token+or+access-violation+or+access-control+or+access-modifiers+or+access-denied+or+accessor+or+access-specifier+or+accesscontrolexception+or+accessory+or+access-point+or+accessoryview+or+access-log+or+access-rights+or+access-keys+or+accessibility-api+or+access-levels+or+accesscontrolservice+or+accessibilityservice+or+vba+or+vbaccelerator

which gives you:

[image: unanswered with expanded wildcards]

and just add [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) and [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) to your ignored tags list to have them displayed dimmed or have them removed from the page on pageload (check the *hide ignored tags* option in your prefs page).

Comment: Thanks. I don't mind changing the unanswered part. Now that I know this and have replaced the spaces with + this seems to work nicely.