# Not tags don't appear to be working for me

Tags: support, tags, search

This is a follow on from a question I asked not long ago: [Why is this Stack Overflow URL returning unexpected results?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195957/why-is-this-stack-overflow-url-returning-unexpected-results?noredirect=1#comment618113_195957).

I had thought initially that my URL was now working correctly but it appears that the *not* tags are still not working as I expected. This is still a great improvement one the results I was getting before the previous question, but it would be great if I could get the exclusions as intended.

The URL I am using at the moment is:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python+or+sql+or+sqlite+or+plsql+or+oracle+or+windows-7+or+cmd+or+excel+or+access+or+vba+or+excel-vba+or+access-vba+-django+-.net+-google-api+-flask+-pyramid+-c%23?sort=newest
```

As you can see from the screenshot below questions with tags that I am trying to exclude such as django and sql-server are still appearing:

> [image]

This may be a case of me misunderstanding what the *not* tag should do. I had hoped that this would take precedence over the tags that I have asked to be included but perhaps this is not the way that it works?

Any ideas?

Comment: The questions listed match both searched-for tags *and* excluded tags. My guess is the explicitly listed tags take precedence. Use ignored tags instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, how do I use ignored tags instead? Do you mean just don't list Python etc in the inlcuded tags? What I had hoped to be able to get was only questions that include tags (x, y or z) but do not include tags (a, b or c).

Comment: Add the tags to your [ignored tags list](http://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/2012446) and optionally have them hidden altogether.

Comment: I understood what you wanted, but I don't think the search engine lets you have it that way.