# Can I search for 2 different tags at the same time?

Tags: discussion, search, tag-search

I am aware that you can search for multiple tags such as [css] and [jquery], which will show questions with both of those tags. But is there a way to search with 'or' rather than 'and'? So that the search will show any question that has any tag that's listed?

Comment: Are you using the new navigation on Stack Overflow?

Comment: What do you mean by new navigation? I just search the tags in the search bar ex. '[html] [css]'

Comment: Okay, why you don't experiment? Pick `[html] or [css]`...

Comment: As the above link says, this is a helpful link as well: [How do I search for questions with specific tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-specific-tags/5230#5230)

Comment: Okay that's what I was looking for, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Using your examples, you can search `[css] or [jquery]`. This will result in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css+or+jquery), which shows posts with both css and jquery tags, or only one of the two.