# What are all the search operators and what do they do?

Tags: support, search

There have been some really useful search operators I've found over time, such as `hasaccepted:no` and `answers:0`. I seriously doubt that I've found all of them. I've searched on Meta Stack Exchange, Meta Stack Overflow, and the Help Center, but I wasn't able to find a list of all the different search operators.

What are all of the search operators and what do they do?

Comment: Have you visited the [search help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching) page?

Comment: @Arulkumar thanks, I would never have thought it would be in that section of the help center.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I search for questions with (or without) specific tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5229/how-do-i-search-for-questions-with-or-without-specific-tags)

Comment: @Arulkumar no, that only mentions a couple of search operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a page in the Help Center:

*https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching*

Also you can simply go to the search page:

*https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=*

And hit "Advanced Search Tips":

[image]

Comment: ```is:q``` and ```is:a``` are shorthand for ```is:question``` and ```is:answer```. The former is one of my favorites since I don't want to read answers without the context of the question.